# How to fix massive lag on django development server?

Tags: django, django-2.0

**OVERVIEW:**

Hi, I have massive lag on my development server as long as I am offline. I'm using windows 10 pro. I have a website on my local environment at 127.0.0.1:8000/. I have a fairly high end laptop that can play high graphics games on it with no problems, and no lag, such as fortnite. But my local development server is super slow, and does not stop being slow unless I get online *(even though I'm using the development server).* This problem started back in may of this year, and back then I asked some other programmers who had no clue how to fix it. It had never been that way before, and I don't want to be online all the time...

**EXAMPLE OF PROBLEM:**

For a developed project while I'm offline: `python manage.py runserver`, paste 127.0.0.1:8000/ into the browser, wait ~10 seconds, then the background color shows up (no text yet), ~10 secs later some pics show up with some textless  elements that have background colors, ~8 seconds after that the text shows up in portions of those elements, and ~10 secs after that the webfont and the rest of the page finally shows up.

For a fresh, brand spankin' new project made 5 seconds ago with nothing added to it: The same thing happens on the django success rocket page that pops up.

And everytime I do this, to even get the images/etc to show up, I have to click in the terminal and hit any button, like spacebar. Then every once in awhile the terminal decides to be a bro and shows a new line with a new GET or POST request *(depending on what app I clicked on the page).* Example:

```
[04/May/2018 19:21:09] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 59899
[04/May/2018 19:21:33] "POST /vote/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7648
[04/May/2018 19:21:33] "GET /vote/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7648
[04/May/2018 19:21:59] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 59900
```

If I'm online so the website runs fast/perfect: I noticed that if I highlight something in my terminal, the requests won't go anywhere, so I have to click in the terminal and hit any button to unhighlight it, and then it will run just fine. But when offline and nothing is highlighted, it's super slow.

**THINGS I HAVE TRIED:**

1. Full system scan with bitdefender (antivirus)... No problems found, and no improvements.
2. Defragged hard drive.... No improvements.
3. Went back to the previous lightning fast versions of my developed projects before ANY changes were made.... No improvements. Still super slow.
4. Ran the developed projects, and the brand spankin' new one on a different hard drive... No improvements.
5. Cleaned the registry with regseeker... MASSIVE IMPROVEMENTS so it will be lightning fast again, but it's very short lived (about 3-4 minutes).
6. Checked my CPU and RAM usage while requesting pages and clicking my apps... Nothing ever spikes anywhere even close to 100%. About 50% is max at all times with all my programs running. So I always have plenty available.
7. Installed Django-debug-toolbar. And my pages load fast according to it. Bigger pages take about 246ms, and smaller pages about 40ms. So the problem doesn't show up here, it only shows up in my terminal HTTP requests and on the browser window by taking forever to load.
8. Using `python manage.py clearsessions` on the database... No improvements.
9. A full clean install of windows 10 pro. Not the 1/2 assed install that lets you keep all your programs, but a full wipe, diaper change, and reinstall of everything. I actually did this 5 times *(long story)*.

**QUESTION:**

Does anyone have any idea what's going on??? If you have no idea, do you know anywhere I can go to figure this out??? I would love to finally get rid of this bug. Back when this problem started I spent about 10-12 hrs a day for 2 weeks doing all the above, until I gave up *(most of my problems were from #9).* Having had some success asking quesitons here, I figured I'd ask.

Comment: Use Mac OS/Linux, this part i liked the most `the terminal decides to be a bro`

Comment: It could be your computer, your network adapter, or a software (such as an antivirus, firewall etc) you are using. I have a Windows 10 based development PC too and don't experience those issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Truly, the terminal gods hath smiled upon me this day!

I disabled my firewall, restarted my computer, and it works lightning fast again while offline.

If I didn't restart my computer after disabling that, it doesn't work. No idea why that is, but this bug was annoying, and I got sick of having to be online everytime I wanted to make an app.

Thanks to whoever suggested it might be something with my firewall, but later deleted their suggestion/answer.

**UPDATE 10/9/2018:**

I remember this problem began sometime around when I had an antivirus update. A couple days ago, I restarted my computer cause the antivirus had another update, and all of a sudden I don't get the lag anymore, even if keep the firewall on, but am still offline.

Comment: It sounds like it might have been a networking issue. If your Django app attempts to access some outside service it can either timeout (slow) or immediately receive "connection refused" error (fast). Depending on how your firewall is configured either one of these things might happen.