# Django and Polars strange slow response behavior

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-polars

I am using Django rest framework with polars for creating reports.

When having big response data, about 3,500 records, a response takes about a minute.

At first, I thought the polar process was slow, but then I timestamped the beginning and end, and found out the whole process is about 1 sec.

```
class TaskViewSet(SearchViewSet):
    """Task view set"""

    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    search_vector = SearchVector("id", "name")
    permission_classes = [D7896DjangoModelPermissions]
    filter_backends = [
        filters.DjangoFilterBackend,
    ]
    filter_class = TaskFilter
    pagination_class = None

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        start_time = datetime.now()
        branch = request.GET.get("branch", None)
        orders = request.query_params.getlist("order", [])
        events = request.query_params.getlist("event", [])
        production_orders = request.query_params.getlist("production_order", [])
        start_date = request.GET.get("date__gte", None)
        start_date = (
            datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            if start_date
            else start_date
        )
        end_date = request.GET.get("date__lte", None)
        end_date = (
            datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date() if end_date else end_date
        )

        # Validate branch is present
        if not branch:
            raise ValidationError("The 'branch' field is missing.")
        _, tasks = WorkOrderManager.get_work_orders(
            branch, start_date, end_date, orders, events, production_orders
        )
        if not tasks.is_empty():
            tasks = tasks.filter(pl.col("unused_components_task") == False).drop(
                ["unused_components_task"]
            )
        tasks = tasks.with_columns(
            tasks['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
            tasks['supply_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            )
        data = tasks.to_dicts()
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        end_time = datetime.now()
        total_time = end_time - start_time
        print(total_time)
        return Response(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

Total Time printing in the terminal:

[printing in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urp2r.png)

Postman timing:

[postman timing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihXEb.png)

Then, I thought maybe it was the size of the response.
So I tried to do all the data building but returned an empty dictionary. still took over a minute.

At last, I gave it a try to get the same data from a JSON file and return it, which took less than a second.

Losing my mind over it for a few days, any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried measuring the time at various lines instead of just total?

Comment: This is most likely not the cause of slowness but `tasks['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` is an anti pattern inside `with_columns`. You should use expressions `pl.col('date').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: You are right, it was a chat gpt copy, and it is still using pandas syntax, my bad. 
About timing various line, will try it, but how can that affect if the total time measurement is ok?

Comment: Oh nm the various timing bit, I misunderstood the issue that that is low but effective time is high.

Comment: The polar part (WorkOrderManager) is working on recursive data.
I add time measurement in every recursive call and it is still overall under a second

Comment: It seems like the issue is outside this code like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304811/how-to-fix-massive-lag-on-django-development-server